# Leading zeros leading to wrong sorting answer using inbuilt sort method of javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting

I was sorting a string/array of integers in lexicographical order. 
 A case came when i had to sort a string containing "022" using array.sort. I don't know why it is equating that  equal to "18" when being printed.

```
var l = [022,12];
l.sort();
(2) [12, 18] => output
```

What is the  reason behind this and how to correct it?

Comment: `022` is an octal number literal == 18 in decimal

Answer (score 1):

This isn't specific to the sort. If you just type `022` into a console, you'll get back 18. This is because 022 is being interpreted as an [`OctalIntegerLiteral`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-B.1.1), instead of as a [`DecimalLiteral`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.8.3). This is not always the case however. Taking a look at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Numeric_literals):

> Note that decimal literals can start with a zero (0) followed by another decimal digit, but If all digits after the leading 0 are smaller than 8, the number is interpreted as an octal number. This won't throw in JavaScript, see [bug 957513](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=957513). See also the page about parseInt().

**EDIT:** To remove the leading 0s and interpret the `022` as a decimal integer, you can use [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Javascript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) and specify the base:

```
parseInt("022", 10);
> 22
```

Comment: Can I ask you how you got the reference link so fast? Have you read the specification previously?

Comment: so u r saying that parseInt(array) will solve this problem?

Comment: @HimanshuBhutani Check the edit. You need to specify base 10 to interpret the string "022" as the decimal integer 22.

Comment: thanks @stybl...sry i can't upvote ur ans because of my low reputation points.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to `"use strict";` so that `022` will produce a syntax error instead of octal number:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Deprecated_octal